# Counting points in polygons by weight and class in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, count

I have seen a similar question to [Counting points in polygon using weight and class simultaneously](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364304/count-points-in-polygon-using-weight-and-class-simultaneously-qgis-3-1=), but I was unable to operationalize the answer that I found so far.

I have a point layer with attribute values by groups that I would like to assign to the cells of a grid layer as sums of the different groups.

Ideally, I would receive one column for each group with the summed values of the group that are contained within the grid cells. How can achieve that?

I was going to try a suggestion involving virtual layers, but didn't fully understand which specific parts of the suggested code would need to be replaced with my layer names.

Comment: First things first: Please don't post follow-up questions as answers. Instead do as you did right now, ask a new question, reference the original one and state, why that solutions doesn't work for you. So, please delete your answer in the linked question, thank you. Secondly: Please include relevant code in your question, since links may become obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I deleted the follow-up question from the answers for the thread that I had referred to. Unfortunately, I can't get the code to work, which I would blame on my lack of understanding of the query. 

My point layer "PupilNo" has one column for each year (e.g. "1894") with values (>=0 ) for groups that are defined in a different column ("Society") of the point layer while my grid cell layer "1894SocietySums" only has an "id" column that I would want to link the sums by group and year to.

Comment: Oh, and so far I tried: 

SELECT st_union(B.geometry), B."id", SUM(D."1894")
FROM "1894SocietySums" AS B
JOIN "PupilNo" AS D ON contains(B.geometry, D.geometry)
GROUP BY D."Society"

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using only native QGIS 3 tools.

Let's assume there two layers `"cells"` and `"points"` with its corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Use a `'Join attributes by location'` geoalgorithm

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply a Filter (`RMC > Filter...`) to the output of the Step 1, because there can be points with no overlaps with cells. Simply where `"id_2" != 'NULL'`

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** By means of `'Statistics by Categories'` perform a grouping by two parameters of a single value.

[image: step_3]

And finally get an output in a table format.

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there two layers `"cells"` and `"points"` with its corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to receive one column for each group with the summed values of the group that are contained within the grid cells.

```sql
SELECT c.id AS "cell_id",
       p."Groups" AS "point_gr",
       SUM(p.Data) AS "value",
       COUNT(p.id) AS "points_count"
FROM "cells" AS c
JOIN "points" AS p ON st_intersects(c.geometry, p.geometry)
GROUP BY c.id, p."Groups"
```

The output Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

***Note:*** that the output layer does not contain any geometry since it was specified.

---

**References:**

- [Understanding Join Attributes by Location in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/understanding-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis/305193#305193)
- [Calculating point layer values within polygon features in QGIS 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305165/calculating-point-layer-values-within-polygon-features-in-qgis-2)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear and understandable!

I think that I managed to modify the code accordingly.

Unfortunately, however, it seems like the number of my grid cells (~30,000) slows down the process significantly to the extent that it becomes unusable. I receive a "No error" notification after around 5 minutes, but opening the attribute table or saving the virtual layer consistently crashes my pc or qgis. I am assuming that your query works, but that my dataset isnt suitable for the solution?